# How to define variable inside the __global__ kernel shared between all threads in the grid in CUDA

Tags: c++, variables, cuda

I want to define variable inside __ global __ kernel which will be the same for all threads. 
I found in CUDA programming guide, that I can use __ device__ qualifier for this purpose. However, I got an error: __ device__  variable declaration is not allowed inside a function body.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `__device__` variable at module scope:

```
__device__ int my_val = 0;

__global__ void my_kernel(){
  // my_val will be the same for all threads
}
```

Depending on what you are doing with that variable, you may also want to use the `volatile` [qualifier](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#volatile-qualifier).

Variables that are visible to all threads are those which are defined in *global* memory (i.e. not *local*, and not *shared*). Global memory variables can be defined dynamically, using APIs like `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy`, and pointers to those need to be passed as arguments to your kernel. Or global memory variables can be defined "statically", using `__device__`, which [requires no specific API to allocate](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#variable-type-qualifiers). There is no other method* to define a device-modifiable variable (i.e. non-`__constant__`) that is visible to all threads. And as you have discovered, the `__device__` variable definition belongs at module scope.

(*) actually there are two other methods: Unified Memory (which can be done statically or dynamically) and Host Mapped ("zero-copy") Memory.  Conceptually, from the standpoint of usage in kernel code, Unified Memory will appear to be very similar to ordinary statically allocated or dynamically allocated (non-UM) global variables.  Host mapped memory cannot be defined statically, and will appear to be similar to ordinary dynamically allocated memory, from the standpoint of usage in kernel code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about volatile? There is not much information about this qualifier in programming guide

Comment: The programming guide discusses it [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#volatile-qualifier).  Are there some questions about it that are not answered there?  I don't know how to respond to the question "what about volatile?"  What do you want to know about `volatile` ?

Comment: As I understand, I can define variable inside a kernel, which will be the same for all threads, if I will use volatile qualifier. Is that correct?

Comment: `volatile` is a qualifier that is added to some type of variable definition.   `volatile` added to a *local* variable definition will not be the same for all threads.  `volatile` added to a `__device__` variable definition will be the same for all threads.